# FontAwesomeFX importing only "GlyphCheckBox" and "GlyphsStack", missing all the other important components

Tags: java, maven, user-interface, javafx, fontawesomefx

Hey guys I tried to install FontAwesomeFX but when I import the jar in SceneBuilder it misses a ton of components i.e: fontawesomeiconview etc...

Screenshot of scenebuilder when importing the jar:

[image: Scenebuilder import]

Screenshot of maven:

[image: maven screenshot]

This is how it should be:

[image]

Can someone help? I've been trying for the last 30 minutes but nothing changed. Thanks

Comment: This may have nothing to do with the issue, but what version of Scenebuilder are you using?

Comment: JavaFX Scene Builder 17.0.0

Comment: What happens if you use https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.jensd/fontawesomefx-commons/11.0?

Comment: Remove all your current fontawesomefx jars. Now do a search for `de.jensd.fontawesomefx`. Add every jar except `de.jensd.fontawesomefx`. What happens then?

Comment: Now I only have GlyphStack and fontawesomeiconview (2 out of 7) but it's the only one that I needed to use, problem solved I guess?

Comment: Sounds good! Good luck coding!